# Specifying Python PIP arguments in `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`

Tags: python-3.x, pip, cython, setuptools

I am working on a Windows-based C++ package wrapper for Python which depends on external libraries (DLLs).

`pip install <wrapper package path>` works only if `--use-feature=in-tree-build` is specified in command line (the package uses relatives paths).

Is there a way to enable `--use-feature=in-tree-build`  by default in `pyproject.toml` / `setup.py` so it won't copy the files to a temporary directory?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "in-tree-build" feature would be the default and the only behavior in future versions of PIP, this is why probably there is no way to configure it now